# gwt uibinder set unique ID

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

i try to set unique id for uibinder widget.but fail .my constructor look like below

```
public CustomUIWidget() {



    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

     this.getWidget().getElement().setId(DOM.createUniqueId());

         System.out.println(this.getWidget().getElement().getId());  //put debug line here, value is empty
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Can you please provide some more code?

Comment: are you using gwt2.1? try put debug line on system.out. i tried it's empty. DOM.createUniqueId() does create uniqueID though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is working for me (using GWT 2.1):

ui.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">

    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <g:Label text="test" />
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

the widget:

```
public TestView() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    getWidget().getElement().setId(DOM.createUniqueId());
    System.out.println(getWidget().getElement().getId());
}
```

This creates an output like `gwt-uid-#` where # is an arbitrary number.

The rest of your code is working? It had often happened too my that I had a typo or the like in the `ui.xml` file that didn't produce any visible error (i.e., no stacktrace) but still was erroneous.